# How can I use the position of an AnimatedPositioned widget to show or hide part of a Stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a row of text buttons that, when selected, get a background color and have a text style change.  I have animated the background color so that it slides between the buttons when selected, but I would like to use its position to change the text style on the buttons.

These are the buttons : -

[image]

Ideally as the dark oval slides over the adjacent buttons the colors would change.  I currently have it in a Stack with the light colored text and icons hidden by the darker ones and I'm trying to figure out how to use the position of the slider to hide the darker colored things.  Here's what I currently have:

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: unselectedButtons,
          ),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          top: _selectionTop,
          left: _selectionLeft,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          width: _selectionWidth,
          height: _selectionHeight,
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: selectedButtons,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

I cannot find any documentation that talks about using a relative position of an object to show/hide something.

The code above slides the background oval around, but doesn't change the visibility of the other children in the Stack.

Comment: i don't think it's feasible with `Animated*` widgets - i would try to use `Flow` widget where you have the full control of layouting your children

Comment: @pskink could you show me an example of how that would work?  I've been trying to work it out, but can't quite get it.

Comment: `Flow` class documentation has some sample code